Showing the connection between the doubling map and Bernoulli shift map.
Here is a remaining part of the question I asked here Showing that a set has measure zero? :
Let $S : [0,1) \to [0,1) $ be the doubling map, $S(x) = 2x \pmod{1}.$ I want to show that $\phi(T(\textbf{x})) = S(\phi(\textbf{x})).$
I am just wondering how can I do this? What is $S(\phi(\textbf{x}))$?
Note that the map $\phi$ is defined as: Consider the map $\phi: X\setminus X_{\infty} \to [0,1)$ defined by $$\phi(a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n2^{-n}$$ so $\phi$ sends each sequence $(a_1, a_2,\dots)$ to the point $x$ in $[0,1)$ with that binary decimal expansion.
I also, want to know how can I use the fact that $S$ is ergodic to prove that $T$ is ergodic?
Any hints for the above two questions will be greatly appreciated.
Here is the general setting of the problem that is given in the link mentioned above:
Consider the probability space $X = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ of sequences $x = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots)$ where each $a_i$ is either $0$ or $1.$ Take $\sigma$ to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all cylinder sets $$C(n,A) = \{\textbf{x}| x_n \in A, A \subset \{0,1\}\}$$
that is, those sequences whose $n^{th}$ term belongs to some subset $A$ of $\{0,1\}.$ Let $\mu$ be the measure so that, given a finite collection $A_1, \dots , A_n \subset \{0,1\},$ we have
$$\mu (\{\textbf{x} \,|\, x_i \in A_i, i = 1, \dots , n \}) = \Pi_{i=1}^{n}\frac{|A_i|}{2}.$$
Consider the map $\phi: X\setminus X_{\infty} \to [0,1)$ defined by $$\phi(a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n2^{-n}$$ so $\phi$ sends each sequence $(a_1, a_2,\dots)$ to the point $x$ in $[0,1)$ with that binary decimal expansion.We know that $\phi$ is a bijection. We may assume that $\phi$ is measurable with measurable inverse. Also, we know that if $V$ is a measurable subset of $[0,1)$ and if $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on
$[0,1).$Then $\mu(\phi^{-1}(V)) = \lambda (V).$

You may have more luck with that commutative diagram using AMScd.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27312/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram-on-math-stackexchange-com

@EricTowers thanks Eric! Will use it :)

Sadly, the code can not be used @EricTowers

Other than the uspackage typo, other errors prevent me building your diagram, so I can't help you translate it.

What are the other errors that prevent you? Can not you just remove my code and put your code in an edit?@EricTowers

I edited my code but it still does not work. Can you help me in this @EricTowers

When I try to build either your old tikzcd block or the current block in a new LaTeX document, \tikzcd throws a truly astonishing number of errors.  My best guess is that \arrow won't take "T" red as an argument.  Is there any version of your commutative diagram that builds somewhere (not necessarily here at M.SE.com)?

can you just use yours without anything from me? @EricTowers

How could I guess what your diagram is supposed to be if I can't get it to compile to look at it?


I am just wondering how can I do this? What is $S(\phi(\textbf{x}))$?

For $x$ a sequence, $\phi(x)$ is the real number (one of) whose binary expansion(s) is given by the entries of $x$. $S$ is the doubling map; so
\begin{align*}
S(\phi(x))=S(x_1/2+x_2/4+x_3/8+\cdots)
&= x_1+x_2/2+x_3/4+\cdots\mod 1 \\
&= x_2/2+x_3/4+\cdots.
\end{align*}

I also, want to know how can I use the fact that $S$ is ergodic to prove that $T$ is ergodic?

Hint: Ergodicity is invariant under measure-preserving conjugacies.

what do you mean by measure preserving conjugates?

@Hope Typically $\phi$ such that $\phi\circ T=S\circ \phi$ and $\mu\circ\phi^{-1}=\lambda$ is called a measure preserving conjugacy. (see also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4132091/169085)

Do you know a source of a proof for  "Ergodicity is invariant under measure preserving conjugacies"?

@Hope Most introductory ergodic theory books presumably states or proves this statement; alternatively see my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4558118/169085 . For ergodic theory references see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46889/169085
